# date in mysql sets to 0000-00-00, why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, http-post

I get with method post data from page, and insert into table like this`

```
$b = $_POST['birth'];
//when i write echo $b; it prints 2013-10-13, i normally get data from page

$query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS VALUES" .
    "('$firstname', '$lastname', $b, '$login', '$password')";

if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
 echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
```

And my table is

```
f_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
l_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
birthday DATE NOT NULL,
login_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (login_id)
```

But it sets the time 0000-00-00, don't know why.

Comment: How is the date formated in `$_POST`? Furthermore, no server today stores a password in such way... You should use at least a hash.

Comment: `$b` is a string literal: either quote it as `'$b'`, or better yet use parameterised prepared statements.

Comment: Try `"INSERT INTO MEMBERS VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$b', '$login', '$password')"`

Comment: Thanks to all, i try now.

Comment: CommuSoft, i'm new in web programming, i'll do it later ))

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you probably never make a mistake when you put every data in quotes (either single or double).

```
$query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS VALUES" .
"('$firstname', '$lastname', $b, '$login', '$password')";
```

The `$b` should be in single quotes. It is a date string. If you don't put it in quotes, MySQL will probably calculate "2013 minus 10 minus 13", get 1990 and think: What a stupid value for a date, I'll take "0000-00-00" to indicate the next best guess, because I cannot use NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As Glavić says, the Date type ***must be*** *string-formed* from php, so, it must given in between single quotes '$date' and all the query must be with double quotes, it´s work for me something like this:`$consulta="INSERT INTO registro(Id,Fecha,Cliente,Producto,Conductor,Remolque,Viaja) VALUES(Null,'$Fecha','{$Cliente}','{$Producto}','{$Conductor}','{$Remolque}','{$Viaja}')";` where $fecha y a Date-Type. see afeter Values, the `'$fecha'`